# Parameter not being passed correctly.

Tags: c, recursion

I have a Piece of code here. The code Runs fine and  there is no error shown by the system. Although I have a recursive function the recursion does not occurs.
Here is my code....
What exactly is the problem???

```
int no_of_moves(int n,int s[], int m)
{   int move=0,i;
    if(n==1)
        return 0;
    for(i=m-1;(i>=0&&s[i]!=n&&n%s[i]==0); i--)
    {
        //printf("(%d %d)",n,s[i]);
        move = max(move, 1+no_of_moves(s[i],s,m));
    }
 return move;
}
```

Comment: it does enter For consider n=12 m=3 s[]={2,3,4}. thats y i have that print statement there to check.

Comment: With these args iam getting output `(12 4)(12 3)(12 2)`

Comment: yea now u see the code is entering for but not the recursion.?

Comment: It prints 3 times, it means that function is called recursively 2 times.

Comment: seriously??? man check that i'm changing n with s[i] so the next time it should print (4,2 ) instead of what it is printing.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing easier than add debug output like this

```
int no_of_moves(int n,int s[], int m)
{   int move=0,i;
    printf("Recursion test\n");
    if(n==1)
        return 0;
    for(i=m-1;( i>=0 && s[i] != n && n%s[i] == 0); i--)
    {
        printf("(%d %d)",n,s[i]);
        move = max(move, 1+no_of_moves(s[i],s,m));
    }
 return move;
}
```

Note

```
printf("Recursion test\n");
```

Output

```
Recursion test
(12 4)Recursion test
(12 3)Recursion test
(12 2)Recursion test
```

It means that your function is called recursively `3` times.
The problem why does the function give you wrong output is in passing parameters. But **Q** was

> Program not entering into Recursion

but it does.

Comment: How about Now . if it is entering recursion why the correcct value isnt being passed to the function altough i'm passing s[i] instead of n.

Comment: Ive tried it and it prints exactly what it should print :)

Comment: But why i'm passing s[i] isn't it when it prints s[i]=4 then the value into the parameter should be 4 not 12??

Comment: in recursive state it is not entering the for loop why is that??

Comment: It prints same numbers becouse `for` condition `( i>=0 && s[i] != n && n%s[i] == 0)` is not true anymore, just once, and print of `(12,4)` is in loop where values does not change. So you have to change the condition of for cycle.

Comment: isn't it true for n=4 and s[i]=2 here i=0, s[i]!=n and 4%2==0 atleast it should print (4,2).

Comment: `n=4`, `m=3` in the second call, so `s[i] == 4` and condition `n != s[i]` is not true becouse `4 == 4`.

Comment: yes thats when i=2, s[i]=4 when for loop proceeds to i=0 then s[i]=2 and all the conditions satisfy. why not then

Comment: Man....... Ive just told you that if `i==2`, then `s[i]==4` and `n==4`, then condition `n != s[i]` -> `4 != 4` cannot **never ever** pass.

Comment: its a loop if one condition is false atleast it would move for next value i agree that above condition is false , then it should go for i=1 check: and then again i=0 and check. its not like loops terminate when condition is false for one value.

Comment: There are `&&` -> if one of conditions is `false`, all expression are `false` and in doesnt enter the `for` loop.

Comment: see here n=4, for i=2, s[i]=4 s[i]!=n this is false. for i=1 s[i]=3 n%s[i]==0 this is false but for i=0 s[i]=2 all the conditions are true i>=0 s[i]!=n and n%s[i]==0

Comment: @ShubhamSingh Run it under your debugger and step through the code, line-by-line, recursive-call-by-recursive-call, return-by-return, and inspect and note the values at each stage.  You will then understand exactly what is happening, and you will not need to ask misleading questions that claim, for example, that 'the recursion does not occurs'.

Comment: thanks for the advice but i've tried and didnt get to a solution thats why i'm here u tell me now shouldnt it run for n=4 and i=0

Comment: You should probably mark this as answer, becouse it is an answer, and debug your code in debugger as @MartinJames said. No one will debug it for you. :-) This conversation is getting too long.